# Issue on customer listing in the backend admin panel

Tags: admin, error, listing

I want to see my customers listing in admin backend but here is this type of error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.customer_grid_flat' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer_grid_flat AS main_table

And one thing more, When I run this command "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" for deploy the content then I am getting this error in the command prompt
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1070 Too many key parts specified; max 16 parts allowed, query was: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer_grid_flat (
entity_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
name text NULL COMMENT 'Name' ,
email varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Email' ,
group_id int NULL COMMENT 'Group_id' ,
created_at timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Created_at' ,
website_id int NULL COMMENT 'Website_id' ,
confirmation varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Confirmation' ,
created_in text NULL COMMENT 'Created_in' ,
dob date NULL COMMENT 'Dob' ,
gender int NULL COMMENT 'Gender' ,
taxvat varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Taxvat' ,
lock_expires timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Lock_expires' ,
aw_ca_business_name varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Aw_ca_business_name' ,
aw_ca_business_addr text NULL COMMENT 'Aw_ca_business_addr' ,
aw_ca_reseller_permitt varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Aw_ca_reseller_permitt' ,
aw_ca_contactnumber varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Aw_ca_contactnumber' ,
is_approved varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Is_approved' ,
shipping_full text NULL COMMENT 'Shipping_full' ,
billing_full text NULL COMMENT 'Billing_full' ,
billing_firstname varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_firstname' ,
billing_lastname varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_lastname' ,
billing_telephone varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_telephone' ,
billing_postcode varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_postcode' ,
billing_country_id varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_country_id' ,
billing_region varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_region' ,
billing_street varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_street' ,
billing_city varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_city' ,
billing_fax varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_fax' ,
billing_vat_id varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_vat_id' ,
billing_company varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_company' ,
PRIMARY KEY (entity_id),
INDEX CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GROUP_ID (group_id),
INDEX CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CREATED_AT (created_at),
INDEX CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_WEBSITE_ID (website_id),
INDEX CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CONFIRMATION (confirmation),
INDEX CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_DOB (dob),
INDEX CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GENDER (gender),
INDEX CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_BILLING_COUNTRY_ID (billing_country_id),
FULLTEXT FTI_00A063FC834DF0A41CC9D8ACF8458ECB (name, email, created_in, taxvat, aw_ca_business_name, aw_ca_business_addr, aw_ca_contactnumber, shipping_full, billing_full, billing_firstname, billing_lastname, billing_telephone, billing_postcode, billing_region, billing_city, billing_fax, billing_company)
) COMMENT='customer_grid_flat' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
"
```

For this, I have run php `bin/magento indexer: reindex` but it still showing this error. What should I do to resolve this error?

Information about My environment

Magento ver. 2.3.1

Comment: Does the table exist? Can you check if table `customer_grid_flat` exist in PhpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_grid_flat` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `name` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name',
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Email',
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Group_id',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Created_at',
  `website_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Website_id',
  `confirmation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Confirmation',
  `created_in` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Created_in',
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Dob',
  `gender` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Gender',
  `taxvat` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Taxvat',
  `lock_expires` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Lock_expires',
  `shipping_full` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping_full',
  `billing_full` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_full',
  `billing_firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_firstname',
  `billing_lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_lastname',
  `billing_telephone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_telephone',
  `billing_postcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_postcode',
  `billing_country_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_country_id',
  `billing_region` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_region',
  `billing_street` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_street',
  `billing_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_city',
  `billing_fax` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_fax',
  `billing_vat_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_vat_id',
  `billing_company` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_company',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GROUP_ID` (`group_id`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CREATED_AT` (`created_at`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CONFIRMATION` (`confirmation`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_DOB` (`dob`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GENDER` (`gender`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_BILLING_COUNTRY_ID` (`billing_country_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `FTI_8746F705702DD5F6D45B8C7CE7FE9F2F` (`name`,`email`,`created_in`,`taxvat`,`shipping_full`,`billing_full`,`billing_firstname`,`billing_lastname`,`billing_telephone`,`billing_postcode`,`billing_region`,`billing_city`,`billing_fax`,`billing_company`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='customer_grid_flat'
```